# How to declare and initialize a MutableSet in Kotlin?

Tags: syntax, kotlin

How to declare a `MutableSet<Int>` with the values 1, 2 and 3?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Kotlin doesn't have its own implementations of collection interfaces. You can use standard Java sets such as `HashSet` or `TreeSet`, or any other set implementation out there. HashSet is the most popular one, and the preferred way of creating a HashSet from given elements is using the `hashSetOf` function:

```
val set: MutableSet<Int> = hashSetOf(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use [mutableSetOf](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/mutable-set-of.html):

```
val s = mutableSetOf(1, 2, 3)
```

which is a [kotlin.collections.LinkedHashSet](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-linked-hash-set/index.html) under the hood.